# Looking for a efficient way to bind a large number of identical dropdown lists in Angular 6

Tags: angular

Imagine you have an array of 100 customer records.  I want to render out a list of these customers with a select/dropdown for each.  All dropdowns will have the same 200 options in.  I'm finding this is taking around 7 seconds to render which is too long.  Is there a way to optimise this?  Perhaps somehow reusing the set of options in the dropdowns so they are only bound once and cloned?

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let control of customerArray; let i = index;">
      <div>
        <select [formControl]="control">
          <option *ngFor="let option of options">
            {{option.displayName}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Check this out https://netbasal.com/angular-components-tips-and-tricks-d9e725871d58

Comment: Can't see how that helps.  That article talks about creating a multiselect dropdown.  I want to render 100 normal dropdowns on the screen that happen to have the same set of options in.

Comment: This might help you - new stuff on the market https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngvforlib

Comment: It's only an idea. You can has a custom Form Control that has two states: in one only show a normal input (with a decorator to looks like a combo), in the other state show a dropdown. in (focus show the dowpdown and in blur show the input). In this way you really has only one dowpdown to render each time

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks for clarifying.